# jQuery: Compare 2D array with 1D array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Let's say I have 2 javascript/jQuery arrays in my code.

One 2D array that looks like this (console output):

```
0: {title: 'Freemium', modules: 'Ordering'}
1: {title: 'Standaard', modules: 'Ordering,Invoicing,Cash system'}
```

and one is a standard 1D array that looks like this (console output):

```
['Ordering', 'Invoicing', 'Cash system']
```

I want to compare both arrays to check if the second array matches one of the first arrays. If it does, it needs to return the first array's title column.

To put it into context: Users can select a number of Modules, and when all the selected modules match one of the configured Pricing Plans, the name of the pricing plan is returned.

How would I go about this? I already have both arrays ready in my code, I just need to find a way to compare them and return the first array's title column. I found some solutions to compare two arrays, but never a 2D with a 1D array.

UPDATE:

So my question is perhaps not very well worded or technically correct.

The different plans are added on the page like this:

```
<div id="packages">
    <div class="package" data-title="Freemium" data-modules="Ordering"></div>
    <div class="package" data-title="Standaard" data-modules="Ordering,Invoicing,Cash system"></div>
</div>
```

I am using the following JS code to 'add' the packages to my code:

```
$("#packages .package").each(function(index) {
   var package_title = $(this).data('title');
   var package_modules = $(this).data('modules');
   packages_array.push({"title": package_title, "modules": package_modules});
});
```

Each by the user selected module is added to an array like this:

```
$(".modules .module.active").each(function() {    
   modules_array.push($(this).data('title'));
});
```

(The arrays `packages_array` and `modules_array` are declared at the top of my code)

This is what I have right now, and if someone could point me in the right direction on how to improve my code and how to compare both arrays..

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. If you really want to compare jQuery objects this would be a totally different question and answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? Why is `modules` a string and not an array?

Comment: And why 2D? There's no 2d array in your question.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for the input. I am not that experienced with jQuery and javascript in general, so I apologize if my question wasn't worded correctly. I have just updated my question to offer a little more context about the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first use the array [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function, to convert your selectors into a comma separated string, them use a `forEach()` function in your 2d array and compare each module to your new string value

Edit: To account for unsorted arrays you can first order your selectors arrays with [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and split your modules using `split(',')`, order the resulting array, and `join()` it, resulting in two sorted strings that can be compared

```js
let objectArray = [{
    title: 'Freemium',
    modules: 'Ordering'
  },
  {
    title: 'Standaard',
    modules: 'Ordering,Invoicing,Cash system'
  }
]

let selectorsArray = ["Ordering", "Invoicing", "Cash system"]

let selectorsString = selectorsArray.sort().join()

objectArray.forEach((plan) => {
  let sortedModules = plan.modules.split(",").sort().join()
  if (sortedModules === selectorsString) console.log("found: " + plan.title)
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the order is not the same

Comment: Thanks a lot, this code helped me get to a working solution :)